# Playing with a functional equation

Tags: recreational-mathematics, functional-equations

I was playing with a functional equation and proved the result below:
Let $f$ be such that $$f(f(z))=z$$ If $f^{-1}$ exists then $$f(z)=f^{-1}(z)$$ If $f'$ exists then as $$(f^{-1}(z))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(z))}=(f(z))'$$ then $(z)'=\frac{1}{f'(z)}$ so $f'(z)=1$ then $f(z)=z+C\rightarrow (z+C)+C=z\rightarrow C=0$ so $f(z)=z$. Any error? Did I assume innecesary things?

Comment: What about $f(z)=-z$?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: How could one derive your result? Do you know other solutions?

Comment: My point is only that you must have an error in your proof, since you derive that $f(z)=z$, which is not necessarily true.

Comment: @точкадважды Another counterexample: $f(z) = 1/z$. I don't understand how you arrive at $(z)' = \frac{1}{f'(z)}$, which isn't true.

Comment: @Cocopuffs That function isn't defined on all of $\mathbb R$, but then,he didn't say it was.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Then what's the derivative of $\frac{1}{z}$ at $z=0$?

Comment: @точкадважды You did not specify that $f$ was defined on all of $\mathbb R$. $\frac{1}{z}$ is a function which has the above property on $\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: @точкадважды You're right, $\frac{1}{z}$ is only defined and differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \backslash \{0\}$. I don't think this should be an issue though, and your step $(z)' = \frac{1}{f'(z)}$ still seems incorrect

Comment: By the way, your result is true on all of $\mathbb R$ (although not by your prove) if you add that $f'(0)>0$, which basically means that if $f$ is strictly increasing (rather than strictly decreasing.)

Comment: $f(f(z))=z$ by definition so $(f(f(z)))'=(z)'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(f(z)))}=\frac{1}{f'(z)}$

Comment: Still not seeing that step, @точкадважды. You seem to have messed up the chain rule.  $(f(f(z))' = f'(f(z))f'(z)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $g:\mathbb R^{\geq 0}\to \mathbb R^{\geq 0}$ is such that $g(0)=0$, continuous, differentiable, $1-1$ and onto, and $g'(0)=1$, then you can define a function:

$$f(z) = -g(z) \text{ if } z\geq 0, g^{-1}(-z) \text{ if }z<0$$

Then it turns out that $f(f(z))=z$ for all $z$ and $f$ is differentiable everywhere. (The condition that $g'(0)=1$ is required differentiability.)

So there are a *large* number of such functions, most of them non-linear.

For example, if $g(z)=z^2+z$, then $g(0)=0$ and $g'(0)=1$ and $h(z)=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4z}}{2}$ is the inverse, and we can define $f(z)=-g(z)$ when $z\geq 0$ and $h(-z)$ when $z<0$.

The general non-trivial solution is to pick an arbitrary $C\in\mathbb R$ and $g$ as above. Then define

$$f(z)=\begin{cases}C-g(z-C)&z\geq C\\ C+g^{-1}(C-z)&z<C\end{cases}$$

In particular, $f(z)=C-z$ is an example.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error lies on $(z)' = \frac{1}{f'(z)}$.

All I can see is $1 = (z)' = f(f(z))' = f'(f(z))f'(z)$, so $f'(f(z)) = f'(z)$.

Comment: $f(f(z))=z$ by definition and if both $f'$ and $f^{-1}$ exist, then by $f(f^{-1})=z$ and aplying the chain rule $(f^{-1}(z))'=(f(z))'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(z))}$. As $f^{-1}(f(z))=z$ then $(f^{-1}(f(z)))'=(f(f(z)))'=(z)'=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(f(z)))}=\frac{1}{f'(z)}$. Note that I only apply the chain rule in order to find $(f^{-1})'$, not to find $(f(f(z)))'$.

Comment: I see what you are doing, which is incorrect. If you find out $(f^{-1})'$, you can evaluate it at a certain number, but you can not evaluate it by a function $f(z)$. I think you need to think about what you are doing more carefully.

Comment: Why I cannot evaluate it by a function?

Comment: I think you mean $f'(f(z))=\frac{1}{f'(z)}$

Comment: If you evaluate on a function, then it is not the derivative $(z)'$ anymore. All I am saying is that you make a mistake when playing with derivative.